# Start My App On Volume key Pressed when app is closed

Tags: android

When i exit my app i want to click on the volume button to start it again without clicking on the icon of the app. Cause i will hide the icon and only start the app by the volume button, here is the code and Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //////// this to hide the app icon  ///////////////

    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.test.MainActivity.class);
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

  }


   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {

      //Do something  
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Down working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Please share your error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use broadcast receiver for volume button press.

Register receiver in manifest file

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.CallBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and your broadcast activity look like this

```
public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.package", "com.package.MainActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. an other question please :  Can I open an other app with is  (i tried to use it , but the app crashed) ?